# What is the Smallest Possible Size of WinXP SP3 with IE8

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virtualbox

I tried to remove all known junks from the window dir e.g. $NTUninstall..., temp files, etc and setting no pagefile. But I still got around 4GB usage in c: after fresh installation of the windows(my installation path is winxp sp2 from the CD, then WindowsUpdate to SP3/IE8). Is it possible to go down further? I'm sure there are a lot of unneeded files in window dir but not sure which one to remove. Does anyone ever achieved a smaller size?

If you want to know why, I'm running WinXp SP3 in a Virtual Machine (I'm using VirtualBox) and needed to create a smallest possible OS image to be stored in a USB flash drive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

depends on how adventurous you are - you could use nlite to remove components - drivers for example - before install. Smallest i've gotten it was about 256 mb, with some serious agressive pruning, and running on UPX on system files - risky, and i got lucky, but you have to do it on a running system, and cross your fingers - if you do it to the wrong file, the system might end unbootable.

Comment: nlite is great for installing Windows on a netbook with a small SSD

Answer (score 2):

Use `powercfg -H off` to make sure Hibernate is off (sounds like it is).  Use the control panel -> system -> Advanced to reduce the page file to 256MB.  Those are the biggest consumers of space.

If you really want a small XP install, you're going to want to get a [mini-XP boot CD](http://www.nliteos.com/nlite.html).  Those are customized XP installs that strip out components, but it can also cause problems with programs that expect those components to be there.